# How to adapt div's width to content with flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want adapt the `.flexrow` div's width to content but i can't set it with flex.

HTML

```
<div class="fullwidth">
  <div class="sidebar">
    <p>sidebar</p>
    <p>sidebar</p>
    <p>sidebar</p>
    <p>sidebar</p>
    <p>sidebar</p>
    <p>sidebar</p>
  </div>
  <div class="center">
    <div class="flexrow">
      <div class="card">
        <p>card</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.center {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.flexrow {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.flexrow .card {
  width: 300px;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: red;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

I have created a snippet [here](https://codepen.io/sarovin/pen/KvwypV)

This is an example of what i want:
[image: example]

Any suggestion?

Comment: Which `div` are you referring to?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Each red block to only be as wide as the text within it?

Comment: sorry, i want align the `.flexrow` div

Comment: Try append this value: `justify-content: space-around;` to your `.flexrow` Hope it will help you, if I understand right :)

Comment: @SaroVin When you post a codepen, make sure you don't update the same when trying out suggested solutions. The now linked codepen is different from the original one, hence will confuse users.

Comment: @LGSon oops, i am sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem here is that when an item wrap, whether one use Flexbox or not, its container won't adjust its width to the new content width.

With the existing markup, here is a simple fix in 2 steps to achieve that:

1. Add `justify-content: center;` to your `.flexrow` rule
2. For every possible column you need one less *ghost* element to push elements on the last row all the way to the left. The added elements together with new `.flexrow .card:empty` rule will do the magic.

   ```
   .flexrow .card:empty {
     height: 0;
     margin: 0 10px;
     padding: 0 10px;
   }
   ```

[Updated codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jLEgWL)

Stack snippet

```css
.fullwidth {
  background-color: grey;
  display: flex;
}

.sidebar {
  flex: 0 0 280px;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

.flexrow {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.flexrow .card {
  width: 300px;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: red;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.flexrow .card:empty {
  height: 0;
  margin: 0 10px;
  padding: 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="fullwidth">
  <div class="sidebar">
    <p>sidebar</p>
    <p>sidebar</p>
    <p>sidebar</p>
    <p>sidebar</p>
    <p>sidebar</p>
    <p>sidebar</p>
  </div>
  <div class="center">
    <div class="flexrow">
      <div class="card">
        <p>card</p>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <p>card</p>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <p>card</p>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <p>card</p>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <p>card</p>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <p>card</p>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <p>card</p>
      </div>

      <!-- Ghost elements, if max columns is 4 one need 3 -->
      <div class="card"></div>
      <div class="card"></div>
      <div class="card"></div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: how can i count the columns?

Comment: @SaroVin You simply add _enough_ with ghost elements. Note, to many won't make any difference

Comment: @SaroVin The main problem here is that when an item wrap, whether one use Flexbox or not, its container won't adjust its width to the new content width, hence won't appeared centered in the way you want. The trick I showed is how to solve that with CSS. Another way is to use script

Answer (score 0):

Try this code-example

```
.flexrow .card {
  height: 60px;
  background-color: red;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

I removed the width, so that flexrow can adapt to the content.
Is this what you wanted? If not please specify (maybe a picture?)

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you want is that if you want the sidebar and  the content to be side by side you need to use `flex` on the `fullwidth` div, check the code below:

```css
.sidebar {
  background: black;
  color: white;
}

.fullwidth {
  display: flex;
}

.center {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items:center;
  width:100%;
}

.flexrow {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width:100%;
}

.flexrow .card {
  width: calc(33.33% - 20px);
  box-sizing:border-box;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: red;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="fullwidth">
  <div class="sidebar">
    <p>sidebar</p>
    <p>sidebar</p>
    <p>sidebar</p>
    <p>sidebar</p>
    <p>sidebar</p>
    <p>sidebar</p>
  </div>
  <div class="center">
    <div class="flexrow">
      <div class="card">
        <p>card</p>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <p>card</p>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <p>card</p>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <p>card</p>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <p>card</p>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <p>card</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @SaroVin in which sense it does not work ? can you be more specific ?

Comment: the flexrow div is not perfectly aligned

Comment: i changed the answer so the flexrow is vertically centered in the `.center` div , is this what you want ? or you want first 3 cols ( card ) to be at top, and last 3 to be at bottom ?

Comment: @SaroVin from the image i cannot be sure what exactly you want. Can you explain using words not images ?

Comment: @SaroVin check my answer now. ( flexrow is 100% width  - sidebar width, aligned centered on vertical and horizontal axis inside `.center` , the boxes ( .cards ) are 3 on one row . You can change that if you want ( i've set them width 33.33% )

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

Try this one:

```
 .flexrow {
  width: 90%;
  display: inline-flex;  
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  -webkit-align-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
  justify-content: space-between;  
  margin: 0 auto;  
}
.flexrow:after {  
    content: "";  
    width: 300px;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;    
}
```

---

Hope that what you're looking for :)

Comment: yes, but the `flexrow` div is not perfectly aligned

Comment: @SaroVin you can set more correctly width for `.flexrow` it should work fine, if you want align items horizontally.

Comment: ... And/Or play with margins

Comment: @SaroVin, I've update my answer, try play with that, hope it will work for you :)

Comment: @SaroVin, for your responsive just use media queries, that's will solve your issue, so responsive is up to you.

Comment: By the way, is no required in your question. And it's confuse also, but as I say before, just use media queries to set the correct styles for each screen resolution. Tha

Comment: @SaroVin, did you try just take away `justify-content: space-between;` from my code? It can solve your responsive issue as well.

Comment: But, then you will have an issue with centered content :) Nice question. I think, for sure, you have to play with media any way )